# Failed to get Win32 handle for clipboard content error while using sf::Clipboard::getString() SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to make my SFML lib and when I want make paste function something is wrong

```
// in function

if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LControl) && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::V)
        {
            this->text= sf::Clipboard::getString().toWideString(); // text is std::wstring type
            this->object->setText(text); // changes text
            this->object->setTextColor(text_color); // changes text color
        }
```

the console prints **Failed to get Win32 handle for clipboard content** and the text becomes nothing. I don't know what to do with it, I haven't foud any answer yet. Please help

Comment: Hard to answer without seeing sf::Clipboard::getString()